# Scan with wifi direct other device

Tags: android, dns, wifi-direct

Is it possible when scanning for devices/peers with WiFi Direct `onDnsSdServiceAvailable, onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable` to scan more than just instanceName, serviceType, deviceNAme e.t.c but a value set by you. What I am saying is if there is any way for me to set a string and then when the host scans the device to scan that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not when you are scanning for devices/peers as you asked but when you are scanning for Services. Which I guess is what you are doing since you mentioned the corresponding methods.

In the part where you instantiate the Service you can set a record which is a `map<String,String>`, this record will be send to devices discovering the service in the method `onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable`.

So what you should try is setting the record in the `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo` whit the key's you want and when you are discovering services you should look for the values in the map you get in `onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable`.

This is all taken from [Using Wi-Fi P2P Services](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html).

I hope this helps

Comment: I get mixed messages here, you marked the answer as the correct one but your comment sugests that it's still not working. Can I help you further?

Comment: No I mean that's what I had already done and it worked, no mixed messages here :p

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this, since WiFi-Direct protocol doesn't support this. Instead, you may embed your string in device/service names.

Comment: Yes but that changes the device name and the user is able to see that, and I cannot seem to change the service, any suggestions?